# Converting String to DateTime in C# in a particular format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How can I convert a string such as **07/26/13** into a **C# DateTime** variable in the following format? **2013-07-26 00:00:00**   (Mysql datetime)

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format - it's just a date and time. And you shouldn't be passing it to the database as a string anyway... use parameterized SQL and set the value of the parameter as a `DateTime` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has `MM/dd/yy` as a standard date and time format, you can just use [`DateTime.Parse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("07/26/13");
```

If it is not, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to parse your string with custom date and time format like;

```
string s = "07/26/13";
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
```

`DateTime` doesn't have *any* implicit format. It has just date and time values. String representations of it have formats. You can format your `DateTime` with [`.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) method like;

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

And by the way, if you want to insert a `DateTime` value to your database, you shouldn't insert it as a string. You should use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) and pass your `DateTime` value to directly to your parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use TryParseExact.Before posting a question try it yourself

```
string date_time = "07/26/13";
DateTime d;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date_time, "mm/dd/yy",  new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                          DateTimeStyles.None, 
                          out  d))
{
  date_time = d.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: `mm` for minutes, you should use `MM` instead.